# Should we have 14.10 tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

When asking [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513967/is-ubuntu-touch-a-separate-distribution-or-the-same-one-14-04) that touches upon the upcoming Ubuntu 14.10 version, I found that there's no [14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/14.10) tag, so I have created one.

Is it okay or should we only create a tag when the version is officially released? I think not, as I can well imagine people needing to seek answers before the version is officially released.

Comment: later when it's on topic

Comment: @hbdgaf I'm afraid it would be a chore  to re-tag all the relevant questions at the moment of official release. Is that policy written up somewhere?

Comment: it's policy to close them previous to that, so there's no need to retag.  they should be closed and asked again later when they're on topic if the uestion persists.

Comment: 14.10 isn't wholly of topic anyway, even now. We seem to bump into that myth every six months.

Comment: @Oli - fair enough, if you look at my posts on meta about beta release options, i'm on the "if you can answer it, then go for it" team.  i just don't think there needs to be a taxonomy for "i hope you know what you're doing" objects

Comment: your 2nd comment to me is a reaon why tagging a question with a release number is not always smart. An error in 13.10 **that is not related to it being EOL** can help a 12.04 or 14.04 user. On the other side: it is soooooooo darn handy to sort the questions on a tag like 13.10 (or Mint) and close-vote the new created ones :D

Answer (score 1):

Let me put it this way:

> A picture is worth a thousand words

[image]